How can (.MDL) materials be correctly imported into Blender for rendering?
Blender 4.2 does not support importing files in (.mdl) format.
Is there any way to import (.mdl) materials into Bledner for rendering?



Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see What should I do if no one answers my question?
